# Is there a way to refer directly to typeclass instances in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The benefit of this could be to store certain metadata about the type in a canonical location. Sometimes, it isn't convenient to have a value of the type before using some instance methods on it; For instance if I have:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: String
  foo = "Foo"
```

This is not actually valid Haskell. Instead it seems I have to have something like:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> String
  foo = const "Foo"
```

and now `foo` will actually have type `Foo a => a -> String`, but I would actually like to be able to do something like having a `foo` with type `Instance Foo -> String`. For this to be useful in some contexts, it might be also necessary to iterate over all (in-scope?) instances, or in other contexts, to be able to specifically materialize an instance for a given type.

I guess the issue is that instances and typeclasses are not first-class entities in Haskell?

Comment: Maybe, but it looks like this `foo` would still require a value of type `a`, no?

Comment: Your `foo` above does not have type `Foo a => a -> [Char]` as you claim, it will have type `Foo a => [Char]` which is ambiguous. If you allow ambiguous types, you will be able to use `foo` through type applications.

Comment: Ryan Scott wrote a pretty nifty summary of the approaches you can take for solving this problem: http://ryanglscott.github.io/2019/02/06/proxy-arguments-in-class-methods/. Not only does it cover the existing answers, but it also talks about some of the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 7):

The "old school" way of doing it is providing a "dummy" parameter whose purpose is nothing but helping the compiler find the appropriate instance. In this world, your class would look something like:

```
data Dummy a = Dummy

class Foo a where
    foo :: Dummy a -> String

-- usage:
boolFoo = foo (Dummy :: Dummy Bool)
```

In fact, this trick was so ubiquitous that the `Dummy` type was semi-standardized as [`Data.Proxy`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.9/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Proxy.html).

---

But in modern GHC there is a better way: `TypeApplications`.

With this extension enabled, you can just straight up specify the type when calling the class method:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: String

boolFoo = foo @Bool
```

(this doesn't only work for class methods; it will work with any generic function, but be careful with the order of type parameters!)

You may also need to enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes` in order to declare such class. Though I'm not sure I remember this correctly, and I don't have a computer handy to check.

Comment: Or, you could have `class Foo a where { foo :: dummy a -> String }`. Then people can use `foo (Dummy :: Dummy Bool)` as well as `foo (Proxy :: Proxy Bool)`.

Comment: as it happens I'm using `DerivingVia` in my real case already, so it is looking like `TypeApplications` will win out - will test soon, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The old way (which I still prefer) is to use a *proxy*.

```
import Data.Proxy

class Foo a where
    foo :: Proxy a -> String

instance Foo FancyPants where
    foo _ = "a fancypants instance"

fooString :: String
fooString = foo (Proxy :: Proxy FancyPants)
```

So we didn't actually need a value of type `FancyPants` to use `foo`, all we needed is a value of `Proxy FancyPants` -- but you can create proxies of any type you want.   This can be done in a polymorphic context too; usually it requires the use of the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

The new way is to use the `TypeApplications` and `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class Foo a where
    foo :: String

instance Foo FancyPants where
    foo = "a fancypants instance"

fooString :: String
fooString = foo @FancyPants
```

Which looks nicer, but working with it in practice tends to be more irritating for a reason I can't quite put my finger on.

Did that answer the question?

Comment: There are two major irritations in practice: 1. You have to know the exact order of the (visible) kind and type arguments. 2. As far as I know, things still don't work in a higher-order context. You can write `foo :: (forall a. C a => proxy a -> A) -> B` or `foo :: (forall a. C a => Tagged a A) -> B`, but not `foo :: (forall a. C a => A) -> B`. So if you need to pass the method to a higher-rank HOF, you'll need some sort of adapter.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like (TypeApplications) will probably meet my needs for now, but @dfeuer is describing irritants that are worth knowing about. In that case, I could switch to one of the other options perhaps (including those mentioned in the blog post mentioned by @Alec) - will give it a try soon! `#Proxy` looks nice otherwise, though its interop with DerivingVia relies on an as yet unreleased GHC version (8.10.1).